# Dynamic file path

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there any way to dynamically alter the path of an image in Corona/Lua?

I'm currently using this:

```
itemImage = display.newImage(inventory[t.ID][1])
```

With t. being the target ID that I pass through an eventListener.

Is there a function that can update the path, in a way that I can update text using .text? 
Something along the lines of:

```
itemImage.Image(inventory[t.ID][1])
itemImage.updateImage(inventory[t.ID][1])
```

I cant find anything regarding this in the documentation.

Comment: Just doing something like `itemImage.Image(inventory[NewIndex])` not work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct method to do that yet. But, If you want to change the images in a proper order, then you can make use of the 'movieclip'.

```
    require "movieclip"

   local myImage = movieclip.newAnim{ "img1.png", "img2.png" , "img3.png", "img4.png"}
    myImage.x=100
    myImage.y=100

    local function changeImage(event)
       myImage:nextFrame()
    end

   Runtime:addEventListener("tap", changeImage)
```

else you need to remove the old image and replace it with new one as follows:

```
    local myImage = display.newImageRect("img1.png",150,150)
     myImage.x = 100
     myImage.y = 100

    local function changeImage(newImage)
        if(myImage~=nil)then
            myImage:removeSelf()
            myImage = display.newImageRect(newImage,150,150)
            myImage.x = 100; myImage.y = 100
        end
    end

    local function callMyFunction()
       changeImage("hair_2.png")
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener("tap",callMyFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace an image like you can change the text.  There are too many variables involved with drawing an image.  You're best bet is to draw your new image on top of your old one then delete the old image.